# Как сделать сортировку в столбцах у `ListView`?

Tags: c#, winforms

Собственно есть `listview`, как сделать сортировку по данным в столбцах? 
Есть столбец процессов - нужно по нажатию на колонку, сделать сортировку по алфавиту.
Есть столбец "память" - нужно при нажатии на заголовок столбца, сделать сортировку.
Так как это сделать?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала добавим свой класс, назовем его `ListViewColumnComparer`, реализуем интерфейс `IComparer` и реализуем из него единственный метод, который в нем содержится `Compare`:

```
class ListViewColumnComparer : IComparer
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }

    public ListViewColumnComparer(int columnIndex)
    {
        ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        try
        {
            return String.Compare(
            ((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[ColumnIndex].Text,
            ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[ColumnIndex].Text);
        }
        catch (Exception) // если вдруг столбец пустой (или что-то пошло не так)
        {
            return 0;
        }            
    }
}
```

Добавить обработчик на нажатие колонки в который запихнем наш класс-компаратор:

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
   this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewColumnComparer(e.Column);
}
```

В принципе всё, будет сортировать в тех столбцах, на которых кликнули мышкой. Можно добавить обработку на индекс сортируемого столбца внутри конструктора `ListViewColumnComparer`, можно вынести в отдельную переменную значение `ASC` 
и `DESC`, чтобы еще и в обратном порядке сортировать. Идея тут ясна - можно развивать.

- > [ListView.ListViewItemSorter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter(v=vs.110).aspx) - возвращает или задает блок сравнения
  >   сортировки для данного элемента управления.
- > Интерфейс [`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) - предоставляет метод, который сравнивает два
  >   объекта.

Comment: интерфейсы не наследуют, а реализуют...Когда вы пишите "реализуем один метод " может сложиться впечатление, что есть другие методы которые допускается не определять.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, внес правку в ответ, чтобы исключить заблуждения и допущения ошибок. Просто не задумывался по поводу того, что это может вызвать противоречие :)

Comment: Теперь другое.У меня ошибка в Form1.cs когда в колумн клик добавил действие - Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "TaskManager.ListViewColumnComparer" в "System.Collections.IComparer". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов)

Значит создаю класс с именем "ListViewColumnComparer" , кидаю туда код, перехожу в форму, добавляю обработчик колумн на лист вью, в код обработчика вставляю тот код и эта ошибка :(

Answer (score 2):

Нужно в событие `listview_ColumnClick` добавить компаратор.

[Здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/319401/how-to-sort-a-listview-control-by-a-column-in-visual-c) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx) достаточно понятно написано, как это сделать.